# alternative means of obtaining .Net 4.5 sdk other than chocolatey

Tags: .net, docker

I'm attempting to run the recently released lab samples from docker for sql server. When I attempt to create the image for the build container, I get an error message stating that chocolatey could not complete the request in

```
RUN Install-PackageProvider -Name chocolatey -RequiredVersion 2.8.5.130 -Force; 
Install-Package -Name microsoft-build-tools -RequiredVersion 15.0.26228.0 -Force; 
Install-Package -Name netfx-4.5.2-devpack -RequiredVersion 4.5.5165101 -Force
```

It appears that if I take the line out for netfx-4.5.2 it works ok, however I'm still without the 4.5.2 assemblies. Is there a means by which I can install these on my container other than chocolatey ?

Comment: Can you point me to the samples you are talking about? Also can you check if internet is working inside your container or not?

Comment: https://www.github.com/docker/labs/sql-server my Internet connectivity is fine as I can install the package from chocolatey on the same Windows laptop I run docker on

Comment: https://www.github.com/docker/labs/windows/sql-server

Comment: The package seems to be there and available too with same version https://chocolatey.org/packages/netfx-4.5.2-devpack

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error I managed to resolved this. The issue relates to the docker sql server lab which can be found in:

https://github.com/docker/labs/tree/master/windows/sql-server

I do not understand how this worked, but it did. The resolution was to move the installation of the netfx-4.5.2-devpack package from Dockerfile.Builder to Dockerfile.v1 . In essense the installation was performed in a different image build.